# Valuations on sections of line bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, valuation-theory, line-bundles

I'm starting to read about valuations.

Given a real valuation $v$ on a (projective complex) variety $X$, centered at $x$, and a line bundle $L$, we can define $v(s)$ for $s \in H^0(X,L)$ by considering a local trivialization of $L$ near $x$, and evaluating at the regular function corresponding to the restriction of $s$.

My questions are:

1) Why is this independent of trivialization?

2) Is there always $s \in H^0(X,L)$  such that $v(s) = 0$?

Comment: I feel like I am close to understanding (1). If we were to write out two trivializations near $x$ and relate them we could just try and show the corresponding regular functions evaluate the same.

Comment: I have asked this question fairly poorly but I can submit an answer myself later.

Answer (score 1):

For (1)

Suppose we have a trivialization in a neighborhood $U$ of the centre. This amounts to saying the restriction of the sheaf is generated by a section $s_0$ on $U$, and any other section $s$ is of the form $fs_0$ for some regular $f$ on $U$. We would then evaluate $v(s) = v(f)$
.
Now suppose we choose a different section to generate the sheaf, $t_0 = g s_0$.

According to the new trivialization $v(s) = v(fg) = v(f) + v(g)$

But $g$ is a section of $ \mathcal{O}_U^\times $, in particular $g$ and  $g^{-1}$ are regular in a neighborhood of the center $c_X(v)$. Therefore $v(g) = 0$ and the result is independent of trivialization.